# Complex integral verification $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+1}$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Obtain
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+1}dx$$

My way to solve this integral was considering a semicircle centered in $z=0$ of radius $R$ (that I called $\Gamma$) considering the variable as complex (consider the prime letters as the negatives, Geogebra didn't let me add the minus symbol):

[image]

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}dz=\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}dz+\int_{|z|=R,\ \  \Re(z)>0} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}dz$$

So, using residues, the two poles are $\pm i$ and only $i$ is inside $\Gamma$, so using the Cauchy integral form:

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}dz=\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\left(\frac{e^{iaz}}{z+i}\right)}{z-i}dz=2i\pi\left(\frac{e^{ia(i)}}{2i}\right)=e^{-a}\pi$$

Then using that

$$\left|\int_{|z|=R,\ \  \Re(z)>0} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}dz\right|\leq (R\pi)\left(\frac{1}{R^2+1}\right)\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow\infty} 0$$

I can tend $R$ to $\infty$ and the second part of the integral will be zero while the other one will be the one I want, so I can finish saying that the value is $e^{-a}\pi$. Is this correct?

I ask it because I wrote it in Wolfram and it says is indeterminate. Could anyone verify if I'm correct?

Comment: The first [example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example) under *"Residue Theorem"* is the same problem as yours.

Comment: I didn't know, but now I know from where my professor took the problem.

Comment: He might not have taken it from there, this is probably one of the simplest possible integrals to practice the residue theorem on, as well as the one for the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so I guess you will find it in nearly every book on those subjects as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your derivation is correct except that the final result depends on the sign of $a$. When $a\ge 0$ the contour takes the upper hemisphere, and the lower hemisphere while $a<0$. In fact, the result is $\pi e^{-|a|}$.